# How to store socket.id across multiple servers nodejs and socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

What is the best way to store user's socket.id across multiple servers? Take for example a simple chat app, if two users on different servers are sending messages to each other, the two servers must store each user's socket id somewhere so they can send the message from one user to another.

Currently I am using a redis hash to store each user's socket id (if they are online) but this doesn't work if a user has two connections (for example they have two tabs of the chat app open). Is the best approach to continue using redis but restructure the data structure in a way that makes it work when a user is connected twice, or would it be better to move to something like mongodb or mysql?

I would also like a way to expire data, for example if a socket id is stored for more than 24h then it should be automatically deleted. I have looked into doing this with redis but it doesn't seem possible to delete only one pair inside a hash. Is expiring data something that can be done in mysql or mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try socket rooms?

[check this link for rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

for example, if a user has multiple connections join them in a room with a unique name(maybe the userId or something)

Comment: Thanks, this is a much cleaner and simpler way to do things than store the socketIds in a redis hash.